# Issues with Cross Contracts calls

Tags: ink, rust, cross-contract-call

I am trying to compile my Rust (ink!) source code for an AMM DEX on Substrate (Aleph Zero), but this is the error I am receiving from the logs:

[image: Screenshot of logs]

The following are the files:

[azero_trading_pair/cargo.toml]

```
[package]
name = "azero_trading_pair"
version = "0.9.6"
authors = ["Edinyanga Ottoho <elzucky@gmail.com>"]
edition = "2021"
overflow-checks = true

[dependencies]

ink = { version = "4.3.0", default-features = false }

scale = { package = "parity-scale-codec", version = "3", default-features = false, features = ["derive"] }
scale-info = { version = "2.6", default-features = false, features = ["derive"], optional = true }

openbrush = { tag = "4.0.0-beta.1", git = "https://github.com/Brushfam/openbrush-contracts", default-features = false, features = ["psp22"] }

[lib]
overflow-checks = false
name = "azero_trading_pair"
path = "lib.rs"
crate-type = []

[profile.release]
overflow-checks = false

[features]
default = ["std"]
std = [
    "ink/std",
    "scale/std",
    "scale-info/std",
    "openbrush/std"
]
psp22 = ["openbrush/psp22"]
ink-as-dependency = []
```

Then the actual router file [router/cargo.toml] is:

```
[package]
name = "router"
version = "0.9.6"
authors = ["Edinyanga Ottoho <elzucky@gmail.com>"]
edition = "2021"
overflow-checks = false

[dependencies]

ink = { version = "4.3.0", default-features = false }

scale = { package = "parity-scale-codec", version = "3", default-features = false, features = ["derive"] }
scale-info = { version = "2.6", default-features = false, features = ["derive"], optional = true }

openbrush = { tag = "4.0.0-beta.1", git = "https://github.com/Brushfam/openbrush-contracts", default-features = false, features = ["psp22"] }

azero_trading_pair = { path = "../azero_trading_pair",version="0.9.6",default-features = false, features = ["ink-as-dependency"] }
psp22_trading_pair = { path = "../psp22_trading_pair",version="0.9.6",default-features = false, features = ["ink-as-dependency"] }

[lib]
overflow-checks = false
name = "router"
path = "lib.rs"
crate-type = []

[profile.release]
overflow-checks = false

[features]
default = ["std"]
std = [
    "ink/std",
    "scale/std",
    "scale-info/std",
    "openbrush/std",
    "azero_trading_pair/std",
    "psp22_trading_pair/std"
]
psp22 = ["openbrush/psp22"]
ink-as-dependency = []
```

Please, if more information is needed to solve this, let me know, but for now, this is the only error here:

"Cannot compile as the target `wasm32-unknown-unknown` does not support any of the output".

Help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I simply fixed this problem by removing the `crate-type = []`

For some reason, new versions of ink! must not be provisioned with crate-types as `cdylib`, `rlib`, or both as the case may be.

It now works like a charm!